# Long string in textview multiple activity hangs for a while

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, longtext

I have multiple and Long strings in `TextView`. When I start my `Activity` it hangs for a while before showing up the actual screen.

I want to know whether, there is any standard way available do this or I am missing something?

I am doing following in my app:

- Strings are loaded from `strings.xml` file.
- One paragraph contains 114 words 704 characters and there are 8 such paragraphs in 8 different `TextViews`
- My app works offline
- I am using `JustifiedTextView` as follows

> ```
>  <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
>                 android:id="@+id/heading"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>                 android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
>                 android:text="long_string_like_paragraph"
>                 android:textColor="@color/subscreenfontcolor"
>                 android:textSize="20sp" />
> ```

Comment: How do you retrieve the string, locally or from server? Update your question with this information and relative code

Comment: Updated my question.... string is saved locally no server side involved.

Comment: Also add the length of your strings

Comment: updated and it's total 912 words / 5632 characters in string

Comment: android.view.Textview is fast, no matter how long your string is. It almost has a flash show, in milliseconds. So i wonder your problem is at JustifiedTextView. check its onDraw() or onLayout() method.

Comment: Yes i just tested TextView is fine.. i also need to justify text.. so if i create my own TextView and justify it that will also cause activity to hang for while.

Comment: you can use ExpandableTextview instead of JustifiedTextView. [check this link i hope this will help you.](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView)